# How to prevent vertex from overlapping?

Tags: java, jung, graph-visualization

I use Jung to draw graphs. Below is a simple graph with tree layout that looks fine. All renderers and transformers are default.

[alt text http://czuk.eu/stackoverflow/ballon_layout_default_size.png](http://czuk.eu/stackoverflow/ballon_layout_default_size.png)

Now, I have changed the default size of the nodes to 100px by setting a custom `VertexShapeTransformer`. The problem is that the nodes started to overlap. Here you can see how it looks:

[alt text http://czuk.eu/stackoverflow/ballon_layout_size_100px.png](http://czuk.eu/stackoverflow/ballon_layout_size_100px.png)

Is it possible to get rid of the vertex overlapping? Is it a matter of layout or some kind of shape transformation?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After not so long investigation I found out that there are two static attributes responsible for setting the minimum distances between vertexes. These are `TreeLayout.DEFAULT_DISTX` and `TreeLayout.DEFAULT_DISTY`. Unfortunately, those attributes define a fixed minimum distance between vertexes but do not consider the real size of each vertex that may differ. The setting is valid for the `TreeLayout` and the `BalloonLayout` that extends the `TreeLayout`.

I also tries other layout but I could not find an analogical solution. This issue is for another question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

When you create a `TreeLayout` you can specify the `TreeLayout.DEFAULT_DISTX` and `TreeLayout.DEFAULT_DISTY` in the constructor:

```
TreeLayout treeLayout = new TreeLayout<String,Integer>(graph,100,100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to put a greater distance between the nodes? You started with a certain distance with a certain size nodes. When you increased the size of the node you reduced the space between them, to compensate extra distance needs to be put between the nodes to keep them from overlapping.

Comment: I do not know nothing about graph layout algorithms, but should not they consider the node size?